# Not able to build qt program

Tags: qt

```
13:42:04: Running steps for project untitled...
13:42:04: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
13:42:04: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\nimisha\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.5148.297.jom
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\nimisha\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.5148.656.jom
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\5.0.2\msvc2012_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\nimisha\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_mainwindow.obj.5148.890.jom
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
jom: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\build-untitled-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2012_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mainwindow.obj] Error 1
```

These are the errors i am facing. I have set path, downloaded everything but still errors. the project is building but stops in between and shows error...

Comment: these are the errors i am facing. i have set path, downloaded everything but still errors. the project is building but stops in between and shows error....

Comment: You should really provide more detail... simply coming here and posting the compiler's log isn't gonna get you any help. Add some code, use the markdown formating in the question editor and explain as much as you can about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi user22... Sorry but this is not the way for asking to our community. Please look another questions to understand which is the best way to ask for something.

Comment: sry sir for such messed up qstn bt if i would have known what is going on and what is exactly problem , i would have never asked..

Answer (score 1):

This bit is the issue.

```
    'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Looks like you haven't got your Visual Studio command line tools in you path. You can either use the Shortcut "Open Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)" that is normally installed, or from a command prompt run

```
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
```

These instructions are for VS 2010, if you have 2012 you'll need to change the path accordingly.

Comment: i have already done this. A cmd opens and then gets closed automatically in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have no `PATH` entry for `bin` directory of your Visual Studio. Chech your environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have Visual Studio 2010 installed in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with QTCreator go to Extras->Options and select a ToolChain. If MSVC is not detected automatically setup the path manually. In your project settings setup your config to use the MSVC toolchain.